# Сколько операций сделает наивный алгоритм для вычисления НОД, если в каждом числе по 10 десятичных знаков?

Tags: алгоритм, числа, анализ

Ниже представлен наивный алгоритм для вычисления НОД двух целых неотрицательных чисел a и b.

[image: NaiveGCD(a,b)]

Как посчитать сколько операций сделает этот алгоритм, если a и b это числа в каждом из которых по 10 десятичных знаков?

Comment: 1. Почему `d|a` а не `a|d` (и для `b` тоже)? 2. Почему перебор до `max(a, b)`  а не до `sqrt(min(a, b))`?

Comment: Это вопрос по теории алгоритмов, то есть по существу по математике, а не по программированию. Не говоря уже о том, что спрашивать нужно вашего лектора.

Comment: @tutankhamun, ну так "наивный" же )) а `d|a` скорее всего значит "d делит a", поэтому так

Comment: "сколько операций" - что значит? очевидно, что цикл будет выполняться `max(a, b)` раз, столько же раз будет выполняться проверка, а `gcd <- d` будет выполняться столько раз, сколько чисел в gcd

Comment: @BOPOH Ну так если настолько наивный, то почему тогда уже не до `+∞` :) А насчет записи `d|a` вы точно знаете? Можете меня лицом в ссылочку про это ткнуть?

Comment: @tutankhamun, если до плюс бесконечности, то это уже не алгоритм, а про `d|a` ссылка в вопросе (я про картинку), откуда-то же это было взято? так там, значит, так и считают. Могли и `d % a` обозначить - имеют право

Comment: @tutankhamun `d|a и d|b` означает на этом псевдоязыке, что **d** делит и **a** и **b**.

Comment: @BOPOH задача в том чтобы дать примерную оценку для количества операций, которые выполнит алгоритм, если на входе в каждом числе по 10 цифр. Т.е. тут задано конкретное ограничение.

Comment: @tutankhamun d|a - это "d делитель a", а наоборот - это вертикальное троеточие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл выполняется max(a,b)-1 раз. На каждый цикл приходятся две операции % (в соответствии с замечанием Mike, до второй операции обычно дело не доходит), одна операция &&, одна операция перехода (операция присваивания выполняется редко и потому не в счёт).
Ответ: ~ 3max(a,b) операций.

Comment: На счет двух операций % не соглашусь, все нормальные языки при && не вычисляют второе выражение, если первое не выполнилось. так что вопрос в частоте выполнения первого выражения %

Comment: @Mike Замечание принято, ответ корректирую.